# How to get listBox selected item as KeyValuePair<string, string> in C#?

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem, bindinglist, key-value

`ListBox` object is binded with `BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

On SelectionChanged event I need to get selected item as `KeyValuePair<string, string>`

Following code gives error because KeyValuePair can't be used as reference type.

```
KeyValuePair<string, string> selectedProperty = listProperties.SelectedItem as KeyValuePair<string, string>;
```

What is good work-around for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using a direct cast instead of `as`:

```
var selectedProperty = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)listProperties.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: this is a great answer